# ActiveModel::AttributeError rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i'm a complete Rails newbie and would appreciate any assistance.

I'm currently getting an error when I try to select the distinct sources from my Users table. So, the SQL query would be pretty straight forward. Something like this:

```
select distinct source from users;
```

or

```
select source from users group by source;
```

the problem is that in my ".erb" file, i have this:

```
<%= f.select :source, User.find(:all, :select => "source") %>
```

i've also tried this:

```
<%= f.select :source, User.select(:source).group(:source) %>
```

the problem is i'm getting this message:

```
missing attribute: first_name
```

obviously, i'm not selecting first_name, but i have noticed that in my "to_s" method that someone else wrote, the return value is

```
full_name.blank? ? email.gsub(/(.).*(.)@/,'\1..\2@').gsub(/@(.).*(.)\.([^.]+)/,'@\1..\2.\3') : full_name
```

where:

```
def full_name
  "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}".strip
end
```

so, it seems that somewhere, something is implicitly calling "to_s" and is not finding the first_name attribute.

outside of modifying my to_s method (which is used widely in the code base) how can I simply select a list of distinct sources from the User table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that using the `select` method the query will only return the `source` column of the table and for the select you'll need at least two parameters, what you could do is something like:

```
<%= f.select :source, User.find(:all,:select=>"source",:group=>"source").map {|u| [u.source,u.source]} %>
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need (works when tested). Could you explain a little bit about what's happening and perhaps why this worked in comparison to the original code snippet?

Comment: @Ramy Well the select helper works with a two level `array` like: `[["red",1],["blue",2],["green",3]]` where the first item of the inner array is the label text that will be shown in the select element, and the second is the value that will take place on the select value that will be sent on with the form, the with `map` we generate an array and the items we're pushing are the inner arrays.

Comment: @Ramy and the other issue is that your query only returns one column and the `select` helper is waiting for at least two columns: `name` and `id` since you don't have a column called `name` it will search for the column `firs_name` on your table because it's the closest to the default column `name`

Answer (score 1):

Ideally I would create source model that has_many users, but if you need quick solution:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.sources
     all.group(:source).map(&:source)
  end
end
```

in controller:

```
@sources = User.sources
```

form:

```
<%= f.select :source, @sources.map{|s| [s,s]} %>
```

This should work.